# Delete content between two lines using powershell

Tags: powershell, coding-style

Hi I have a block of code in which i need to delete values that are present in an array but that is need to be done using the regex which i am not able to accomplish if any one could help me in this will be really helpful.

Following is the block of code:

```
$arr = @("Abd","xyz")

  imports: [
    ddd,
    xxx,
    yyy,
    Abd,
    fff,
    xyz,
    zzz,
    nnn,
  ],
```

i want to accomplish is that all the values present in the array should be deleted between "imports: [" and the first instance of "],"

Comment: does this need to run on PoShv2? if not, please remove that tag.

Comment: is all this in one file? it will give errors if it is in a PS1 file ... so, what is the source of the text to work with?

Comment: this is one file but it has code above it and below it but i just want to read the data from the file and work only on this specific block of code and save the file after deleting the values from the array this is not a ps1 file it is a .ts file @Lee_Dailey

Comment: so this must be treated as a data file. OK. [*grin*] how predictable is the layout? will the array ALWAYS be 1st? will it ALWAYS start with `$Arr` and be on one line? will the `imports: [..],` block ALWAYS be the last thing in the file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this could work for you:

For demo, I'm using a Here-String, but in real life you would want to load it from file with

```
$txt = Get-Content -Path 'X:\input.txt' -Raw  # read as single string
```

The code uses regex to get the part **between** `'imports: ['` and `']'`.
It then separates the lines and gets an array of the lines that do not match anything from the array in variable `$block`.
When that is done, the original textblok that was found in $matches[1] and saved in variable `$toReplace`, is replaced by these filtered lines (re-joined with newlines).

```
$txt = @"
  imports: [
    ddd,
    xxx,
    yyy,
    Abd,
    fff,
    xyz,
    zzz,
    nnn,
  ],
"@

$arr = "Abd","xyz"

# join the values from the array with the regex OR operator `|`
$remove = ($arr | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

# test if we can find the block of text between 'imports: [' and '],'
$txt = if ($txt -match 'imports: \[([^]]+)') {
    $toReplace = $matches[1]
    $block     = $toReplace -split '\r?\n' | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $remove }
    $txt.Replace($toReplace, ($block -join [Environment]::NewLine))
}

# output on screen
$txt

# output back to file
$txt | Set-Content -Path 'X:\output.txt'
```

Output will be

```
  imports: [
    ddd,
    xxx,
    yyy,
    fff,
    zzz,
    nnn,
  ],
```

Regex details:

```
imports:\      Match the character string “imports: ” literally (case insensitive)
\[             Match the character “[” literally
(              Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [^]]        Match any character that is NOT a “]”
      +        Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: how to replce it inline in the file and can you help me explain the regex where is the endpoint mentioned so that i can understand better

Comment: @sachinsafale I have edited my answer and put in explanation